# Google Spread Sheet Api | Invalid Application name Parameter name: ApplicationName

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have followed the [Google APi Tutorial for Dot net](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet). But on executing the code with same steps, mentions in the tutorial at the following code, the Invalid application name exception showed.

```
var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });
```

Comment: what you have pass in ApplicationName?

Comment: What happens if you comment that line out ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears the quickstart has a bug. ApplicationName doesn't appear to accept spaces. Changing the line 21 to:

> ```
>     static string ApplicationName = "Google-Sheets-API-Quickstart";
> ```

worked for me.